# Email address as resource identifier in a REST API

Tags: rest, natural-key

Say my application has users, and each user is uniquely identified by their email address. In that case, it makes sense to use the natural key of email rather than using an auto incrementing ID as the primary key, which is common in most systems.

Then, in my REST API, would it be okay to access a particular user like this?

```
https://api.whatever.com/v1/users/john@smith.com
```

Traditionally, you'd use the user ID in place of `john@smith.com`, but in my application the email address is the unique identifier for user accounts.

What would you pick? Using email as a natural key in REST URLs or create a user ID field to use instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use a user id. A person and their email address don't have a 1 to 1 relationship and they don't have the same life cycle, so using one as the identifier for the other is a bad idea.

People may have more than one email. Maybe they don't have an email account (it happens). Maybe they change their email. If you use the email address as the key, you might run into problems later on.

Comment: I never considered the idea of emails changing, that would mean that if I use the email as the primary key then the primary key will change every now and again and I'm pretty sure that's bad practice also. Thank you!

Comment: Another thing to consider is leaking of private information in your server’s log. Using an opaque user id you don’t leak the email directly.

Answer (score 1):

Should be url encoded
      `https://api.whatever.com/v1/users/john%40smith%2Ecom`

Else fetching by id could by faster than by mail, and maybe you want to open the API to another application person, that should get the knowledge of the E-Mail address

Comment: how would this work if the email has numbers inside like: abc123@123abc.com?

Comment: same way, that would be abc123%40123abc%2Ecom

Comment: found a better way, just the email address but end with a '/' so like this : 'hts://a/v1/users/john@smith.com/' just adjust the route